# How to manage the get-query parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have such view:

```
@model MvcA.Models.SellsLiveSearch
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search","Search",FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend> parametrs</legend>
        <select id="HowManyRoom" name="HowManyRoom"><option></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5>">4</option>
        </select>

        <select id="TimeRange" name="TimeRange"><option></option>
        <option>s</option>
        <option>ss</option>
        <option>sss</option>
        <option>ssss</option>
        </select>



        <input type="checkbox" name="TypeHome" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="TypeHome" value="2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="TypeHome" value="3" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="TypeHome" value="4" />


         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

How to do that instead of empty parameters in GET request

(example: search?**HowManyRoom=**&**TimeRange=**&TypeHome=1)

passed only specified 
(example:search?TypeHome=1)

Edit:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Search(SellsLiveSearch Dol)
        { return View(); }
```

That's all i wrote

Comment: You need to show the signature for the controller method.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, i add... I just started to write. And i can correct the shape of the controller and view if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form will post back all HTML form elements.  The only way to remove them is to post the form using javascript and only posting the elements you want.

You can use jQuery to remove the empty HTML text elements like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Search').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#Search select').each(function() {
      $(this).val() == "" ? $(this).remove() : null;
    });

    $(this).trigger('submit');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply them from the form, the properties will have the default value for their type anyway, whether you include them in the query string or not.

Make your model parameters nullable:

```
public class SellsLiveSearch
{
    public int? HowManyRooms { get; set; }
    public int? TimeRange { get; set; }
    public int? TypeHome { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, verify they are set:

```
public ActionResult Search(SellsLiveSearch model)
{
    if (model.HowManyRooms.HasValue)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```